# How to get all objects using hibernate-core-5.2.0.Final.jar

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, jpql, hibernate-criteria

I did this in earliest vesions of Hibernate as below

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(TestCase.class).list();
```

But `createCriteria` method is deprecated in **5.2.0.Final** version:

```
/** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    Criteria createCriteria(Class var1);
```

What is the alternative solution for this simple example?

Comment: Docs mention using JPA criteria instead.

Comment: Use JPQL. Criteria is useful when creating dynamic queries with various optional... criteria. `select t from TestCase t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found type-safe solution in this way:

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public List<TestCase> findAll() {
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<TestCase> cq = cb.createQuery(TestCase.class);
Root<TestCase> from = cq.from(TestCase.class);
CriteriaQuery<TestCase> all = cq.select(from);
TypedQuery<TestCase> allQuery = em.createQuery(all);
return allQuery.getResultList();
}
```